# External process Invoking shell script with java

Tags: java, shell, arguments, informatica

We have a shell script `RunIndexer.sh` with the following content. The `indexer.jar` application takes two parameters which are true and true.

```
java -jar indexer.jar true true
```

Executing the shell script from the shell works perfectly fine. But when we have Informatica invoke it, it does not seem to be doing anything. I played a bit with the script and found that Informatica is able to invoke `java` and is able to see `indexer.jar`; but the application does not get executed at all. I checked for it in `ps -ef` as well.

What could be happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When executing the shell script from Informatica Command Task or Post Session, you have to make a note of these points: 
1. Give absolute path to that script. 
2. Don't forget to explicitly mention the shell name in which you want your script to run in i.e.(#!/bin/sh/). 
3. One more thing can be checked if the user from which informatica is trying to run script has the permissions to run java code.